# Unexpected scheduler behaviour

Tags: distributed, dask

In a simple workflow, which is as far as I can tell embarrassingly parallel (please correct me), I observe a strange order of execution by the dask.distributed (and presumably the multiprocessing) scheduler.

To illustrate the process, I have set up a similar problem with 5 instead of 60000 partitions, which yields the following dask graph:

[image]

The yellow boxes are 'from_delayed' in the real case.

The underlying workflow is as follows:

1. Read in data
2. Merge the resulting dask dataframe with a pandas dataframe. As far as I can tell from the dask documentation, this should be a "Fast and common case".
3. Select data based on the result
4. Apply a function on each partition

To my surprise, all the data is read in in the first step, consuming approximately 450GB out of 500GB memory. After this, the lambda function is applied in parallel, but it is not using all workers, apparently, only 2-3 at a time are active. Maybe the scheduler hesitates to use more cores because the memory is almost full? When I run the code on smaller problems (~400 partitions), the data is still loaded to memory completely, but afterwards the execution uses all available cores. I've tried to use `repartition` in the very large case, but it did not seem to have an impact.

I investigated this using the distributed scheduler, but it seems to be the same for the multi threaded scheduler.

Maybe the 'merge'-step causes the bottleneck? Are there any other obvious bottlenecks in the given graph?

Comment: I assume the problem is due to wrong usage ... if github might be a better place to ask, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause the behavior that you're describing.  Are you able to produce a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?